# Trying to avoid displaying same image twice

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I am displaying images using a picture box and am timing it in one second intervals. I am trying to avoid displaying the same image twice in succession and am using an arraylist to do this to avoid the same random image following on the other.

This is what I have done. Not working quite as well as I expected and eventually get an exception.
How can I improve on this to avoid displaying the same image twice in succession?

```
Random random = new Random();
        ArrayList imagesList = new ArrayList();
        Image[] images = { imageOne, imageTwo, imageThree, imageFour, imageFive, imageSix, imageSeven };

        do
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < images.Length; i++)
                {

                    imagesList.Add(images[random.Next(0, 7)]);

                    while (imagesList.Contains(images[i]))
                    {
                        imagesList.Clear();
                        imagesList.Add(images[random.Next(0, 7)]);     

                    }
                    picImage.Image = (Image)imagesList[0];

                }

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ind)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ind.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            catch (Exception exe)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exe.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }


        } while (true);
    }
```

Comment: Not the answer but just a hint to improve: I'd not use `Thread.Sleep` in your code. You'll block your UI, refresh the picture, and block again. I'd use a timer instead  in this case to make the UI usable :)

Comment: To improve code - remove `Sleep`, to improve question - format sample with less spaces and provide information on error you are facing. And maybe specify if "one,two,one,two,one,two,one" is acceptable or you want all values to be present but shuffled (shuffle could be good search term for this question).

Comment: I guess that his problem is that random can display 2 times the same value. You could do an array shuffel? Then you can loop through all images at once. Without random. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reorder the images:

```
Image[] randomOrder = images.OrderBy(i => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();
```

and iterate through that array.

You also need to use a timer to change the image because you are currently blocking the UI thread. `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` would be appropriate. Your `Tick` event handler for the timer would look something like this:

```
private int index = 0;

private void Timer_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs args) 
{
  picImage.Image = randomOrder[index % randomOrder.Length];
  index++;
}
```

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) sample code for this `Timer` class is also helpful. Note that there are several `Timer` classes available in the framework and this one would probably be the best here.

Answer (score 5):

You could do a shuffle in stead of getting random numbers. Then you don't need to checking every time if an image is already used. Look here to see how you can shuffle an array: http://www.dotnetperls.com/shuffle. Now you can loop through the array, it is now randomized and you don't get duplicates.

I guess you use the sleep to avoid that you get the same random value every time? You could delete that now. Besides that, it will block the UI.